# Run multiple Subscriptions one after another once each has completed

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I’m trying to programmatically run some SSRS subscriptions one after the other. The reports are all long running and consistently fail if triggered at the same time. At the moment we have about four different subscriptions spread out through the day ensuring that they don’t clash. Unfortunately this can waste quite a lot of time.

The solution I have for this is to create a subscription that is not scheduled to run on all each of the reports in question and then get one job to trigger each subscription one after the other once each has finished running:

1. One job triggers the first subscription
2. Using a WAITFOR command give a few seconds for the subscription to run.
3. Using WAITFOR command check periodically that the subscription is running (‘Pending’)
4. When the WAITFOR check finds that the report has been sent the job triggers the next subscription
   and so on....

I know the code to trigger the subscription:

```
exec [ReportServerWSS].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='SharedSchedule', @EventData='011e83ff-344a-416a-83cb-1a9281e4205b'
```

I just need to know how to use the WAITFOR whilst doing a check and then respond to the results of the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I've figured this out:

```
DECLARE @SubscriptionStatus AS nvarchar(260)


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job '4B7FA89E-0B56-4ED1-9A0F-37E5D03318CB' /*First long running    report*/
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'

SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where subscriptionid =    'E156FD91-E7F9-43EC-8B73-28622834EACB')


CheckSubscription1:
    IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The First long running Subscription is still running'
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'
        SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where     subscriptionid = 'E156FD91-E7F9-43EC-8B73-28622834EACB')
    END

IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    GOTO CheckSubscription1

ELSE

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job '6D3300BC-ACA9-4EEE-A5F9-546635B585E0' /*Second long running    report*/
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'

SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where subscriptionid =        'AD54215A-5B7F-48B2-81B2-52C299875AD6')

CheckSubscription2:
    IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The second long running Subscription is still running'
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'
        SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where     subscriptionid = 'AD54215A-5B7F-48B2-81B2-52C299875AD6')
    END

IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    GOTO CheckSubscription2

ELSE

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job '84FD876A-1945-405E-A344-6279E27DCD68' /*Third long running     report*/

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'

SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where subscriptionid =    '8F446935-5450-458F-9076-7AD9FC78D456')

CheckSubscription3:
    IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The third long running Subscription is still running'
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00'
        SET @SubscriptionStatus = (SELECT LastStatus FROM Subscriptions Where    subscriptionid = '8F446935-5450-458F-9076-7AD9FC78D456')
    END

IF @SubscriptionStatus = 'Pending'
    GOTO CheckSubscription3

ELSE

PRINT 'All long running report run'
```

Thanks,
UT

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in your question I'd definitely say you have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you should really work on the performance and/or [locking strategy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29289/options-for-setting-nolock-hint-in-dataset-queries) of your queries and reports.

Having said that, if you insist "solving" the issue by running reports serially, I'd probably not use built-in subscriptions but go for a more custom solution so you have the control you desire. Create your own app, script, or task that utilizes the [SOAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), call the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) methods on your report one at a time, waiting for each report to finish before starting the next. If you haven't already, set the execution timeout to something high enough for your reports to finish nicely.

Comment: Hi Jeroen - thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately these reports have been optimised, the timeouts have been set to 0 (max) and they still fail to run when triggered together.  The current infrastructure is quite old and we are developing a whole new system  (which could take a few months).  In the meantime I just need to keep everything running smoothly.